# Hybris - Setting "including free shipping" to "No" for all vouchers in HMC

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to set the "Including free shipping" option to no in HMC for all the vouchers available. Is there any way I can do that in hybris?

[image]

To be more precise, I would like to have in default, the free shipping option to No so I won't find this in HMC:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need make changes on type (xxx-item.xml) for changing default value.
You can develop groovy script or batch impex batch for updating existing promotions.

Answer (score 0):

The batch impex which sets the "**freeShipping**" attribute to false for all of the promotion vouchers is:

```
UPDATE PromotionVoucher [batchmode=true];itemType(code)[unique=true]; freeShipping[default=false];
;PromotionVoucher;
```

To run the impex go to hac-> Console -> ImpEx Import.

The above impex works and was tested on Hybris 5.5.1.0